# Search a sentence including given words in impala

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I want to search in a column these 3 words : Hi,teo,code in order to take back the content `'Teo, Hi your pass is 123code'`.

I tried the below query but it is not return the above sentence. Also tried to put `|` inside `rlike` but if I place an `OR` it will show sentences with at least one of these 3 words. Tried also `regexp_like`

```
select *
from db.table
where content rlike 'Hi teo code'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If words are on a specific order, say "Teo"; "Hi"; "code", you can use the following :
`select * from db.table where content like "%Teo%Hi%Code%";` which will look for any string of that form.

Otherwhise, although probably less efficient, the following will work:
`select * from db.table where content like "%Teo%" and content like "%Hi%" and content like "%Code%"`;

Tested this on both sqlite3 and a sql - web version.

**Edit**: I just saw it was tagged as impala. Although my solution would work there too, it is case sensitive.
The case insensitive string finder is `ILIKE` and not `LIKE`